# Defining a two-column box with mdframed

Tags: beamer, two-column, mdframed

I would like to have mdframed boxes which have a picture on the left and some written explanation on the right. Right now I have used the `column` environment in `Beamer` but would like to have the picture within the box.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdenv [font=\footnotesize,leftmargin=-0.2cm,rightmargin=0.0cm]{cvbox}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\frametitle{}
\framesubtitle{~}

\begin{columns}

\begin{column}{0.25\textwidth}
\rule{\textwidth}{4cm}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.75\textwidth}
\begin{cvbox}[frametitle={Adolphe Quetelet}]
Nachdem sein Vater 1803 früh verstorben war, musste Adolphe Quetelet sich schon in jungen Jahren mit dem Aufbau einer eigenen Existenz beschäftigen. Quetelet studierte in Gent und wurde 1815 Dozent der Mathematik. 
\end{cvbox}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the nesting order: put the `columns` environment *inside* the `cvbox`:

```
\begin{cvbox}[frametitle={Adolphe Quetelet}]
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.25\textwidth}
\rule{\textwidth}{4cm}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.75\textwidth}
Nachdem sein Vater 1803 früh verstorben war, musste Adolphe Quetelet sich schon in jungen Jahren mit dem Aufbau einer eigenen Existenz beschäftigen. Quetelet studierte in Gent und wurde 1815 Dozent der Mathematik. 
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{cvbox}
```

You can even define a command for this, if you are going to use this construct many times; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\newmdenv[
  font=\footnotesize,
  leftmargin=-0.2cm,
  rightmargin=0.0cm
]{cvbox}

\newcommand\ImageText[3][scale=1]{%
  \begin{cvbox}
  \begin{columns}
  \column{0.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
  \column{0.5\textwidth}
  #3
  \end{columns}
  \end{cvbox}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\ImageText[width=.8\linewidth]{ctanlion}{Some explanatory comments for the figure go here}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

`\ImageText` has two mandatory arguments: the name of the file containing the image and the accompanying text; the optional argument allows you to pass options to `\includegraphics`.

The result:

[image]

CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.

The [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package offers you some out-of-the-box constructs to manage split boxes, so you could be interested in this package; the documentation of the package contains examples.

Answer (score 5):

If `tcolorbox` could be accepted as `mdframed` alternative. Next code shows a possible solution with a `sidebyside` box.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{cvbox}[1]{sidebyside, lefthand width=.25\textwidth, 
     title=#1, lower separated=false, fontlower=\footnotesize, 
     leftlower=0mm, rightlower=0cm, sidebyside gap=3mm}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\frametitle{}
\framesubtitle{~}

\begin{cvbox}{Adolphe Quetelet}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{frog}
\tcblower
Nachdem sein Vater 1803 früh verstorben war, musste Adolphe Quetelet sich schon in jungen Jahren mit dem Aufbau einer eigenen Existenz beschäftigen. Quetelet studierte in Gent und wurde 1815 Dozent der Mathematik. 
\end{cvbox}

}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: looks really nice!